# Print sum of vectors MIPS

Tags: vector, sum, mips

I am trying to do exercise of MIPS, i have to sum to vector into another vector and then print the sum, I know for sure something is wrong with the sum, because the output is 0 0 0 0 0. Can someone explain me where i am wrong? Be patient please :) Thanks

```
.data
    str: .asciiz "  "
    v1 : .word 3, 10, 5, 22, 13
    v2 : .word 7, 1, 9, 16, 8

    .text
    la $a1, v1
    la $a2, v2

    addi $sp, $sp, -20
    sw $s1, 0($sp)

    add $t0, $0, $0 # i = 0

    somma: slti $t1, $t0, 5 #if i < 5 continua else esci
    beq $t1, $0, esci
    sll $t2, $t0, 2 # i = i * 4
    add $t3, $a1, $t2 # $t2 = v1 + i*4
    add $t4, $a2, $t2 # $t3 = v2 + i*4
    lw $t3, 0($t3) #$t3 = v1[i]
    lw $t4, 0($t4) #$t4 = v2[i]
    add $s1, $t3, $t4 # v3 = v1 + v2
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    j somma

    esci:

    add $t0, $0, $0 # i = 0

    stampa: slti $t1, $t0, 5 # se i<5 continua else fine
    beq $t1, $0, fine
    lw $a0, 0($sp)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str
    addi $t0, $t0, 1
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    syscall
    j stampa

    fine: li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Your `stampa` loop expects a bunch of values to have been placed on the stack, but your `somma` loop doesn't store anything on the stack.

Comment: @Michael What I to do to fix? I saved $s1 on the $sp. I trying to learn MIPS, so i am not so confident

Comment: The only place where you store anything on the stack is _before_ the `somma` loop begins. As for how to fix it: you're already popping elements off the stack in the `stampa` loop. Pushing elements on the stack is just the opposite of popping them, i.e. Subtract And Store instead of Load And Add.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to use some stack space for a temporary vector holding the sum:

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -20
```

allocates the stack space.  The allocated stack space is addressable from `$sp`+0 through `$sp`+16.  (Storing `$s1` there is pointless, so just remove that.)

After the vector element addition into `$t1`, store the element sum result into the temporary vector in the stack, using indexing like you do with the source vectors:

```
addu $t5, $sp, $t2     # compute address of temp vector element to store
sw $t1, 0($t5)
```